# Problem Error Handling in Stored Statement?

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my stored procedure on updating records :

```
ALTER
PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdatetoShipped]
(
@Date datetime,
@SerialNumber
varchar(50),
@User
varchar(50),
@WorkWeek
varchar(50) 
)
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.FG_FILLIN SET Status='SHIPPED',DateModified=@Date,ModifiedBy=@User,WorkWeek=@WorkWeek where (Status='KITTED')and SerialNumber=@SerialNumber

END
```

Then this is my DAL:

```
public int UpdatetoShipped(FillinEntity fin) 
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr); 
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdatetoShipped", conn); 
cmd.CommandType =CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
try
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = fin.SerialNumber; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkWeek", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fin.WorkWeek; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", fin.ModifiedBy); 
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
catch
{
throw; 
}
finally
{
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
}
}
```

My BLL:

```
public int UpdatetoShipped(FillinEntity fin) 
{
DAL pDAL = new DAL(); 
try
{
return pDAL.UpdatetoShipped(fin); 
}
catch
{
throw; 
}
finally
{
pDAL = null; 
}
}
```

And MY UI:

```
string filepath2 = txtPath2.Text; 
Stream stream2 = new FileStream(filepath2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); 
ExcelMapper<FillinEntity> exceltoshipped = new ExcelMapper<FillinEntity>(); 
IExcelParser excelParser2 = new ExcelReaderExcelParser(stream2); 
IExcelRowMapper<FillinEntity> mapper2 = new ShippedRowMapper(); 
IEnumerable<FillinEntity> fillin2 = exceltoshipped.ListAll(excelParser2, mapper2);
int intResult = 0; 
BAL pBAL = new BAL();
try
{
foreach (FillinEntity fin in fillin2) 
{
fin.ModifiedBy = loggedUser;
intResult = pBAL.UpdatetoShipped(fin);
}
if (intResult > 0) 
MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully."); 
else
MessageBox.Show("Record couldn't Updated Check Serial"); 
}
catch (Exception ee) 
{
MessageBox.Show(ee.Message.ToString()); 
}
finally
{
pBAL =null; 
}
```

---

My problem is it always says updated succussfully. But if i updated it again as duplicate update i want to show serial is already updated.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your approach in the SQL alone, including naming convention of the stored proc, and how you run the update. There is no checking in the stored proc for whether the row is already updated for that serial number either, so I'd rethink how you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key change you need to make is to the following line of SQL from your stored procedure:

```
UPDATE dbo.FG_FILLIN 
SET   Status='SHIPPED',
      DateModified=@Date,
      ModifiedBy=@User,
      WorkWeek=@WorkWeek 
WHERE (Status='KITTED')
AND   SerialNumber=@SerialNumber
```

You need to return a value that allows you to determine if this UPDATE has already happened or not, for example:

```
DECLARE @iUpdateAlreadyComplete INT
SET @iUpdateAlreadyComplete = 0;
IF EXISTS 
 (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM   dbo.FG_FILLIN 
    WHERE  Status='SHIPPED' 
    AND    SerialNumber=@SerialNumber
  )
BEGIN
  SET @iUpdateAlreadyComplete = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.FG_FILLIN 
    SET   Status='SHIPPED',
          DateModified=@Date,
          ModifiedBy=@User,
          WorkWeek=@WorkWeek 
    WHERE (Status='KITTED')
    AND   SerialNumber=@SerialNumber 
END

SELECT @iUpdateAlreadyComplete AS Result
```

You can then change your DAL from `return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to:

```
var result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

return result;
```

The return value will now be `0` for a record that has been updated, and `1` for one that didn't need updating as it was already processed.

**Other Notes**

There are a couple of other things that you should consider changing:

- `sp_UpdatetoShipped` is a *bad* name for a stored procedure. [Do not use the `sp_` prefix](http://blog.codergenie.com/post/Do-Not-use-sp_-prefix-for-SQL-Stored-Procedures.aspx).
- Your DAL deliberately `catch`es and re-`throw`s an exception (admittedly in the "best" way), do you really need to?
- Rather than explicitly calling `Dipose()`, use the `using() {}` syntax instead, as this ensures that `Dispose()` is called, even in the event of an exception.

`using` syntax:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdatetoShipped", conn))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: where will i place the return result...
on my dal and ui.
Thanks in regards

Comment: @Crimsonland, I've already stated how to change your DAL in my answer, as for the UI, it's still returning an int, so it's up to you what you do with it =)

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a business rule issue than anything to do with an error.  What you might want to do is to create a dictionary to hold serial numbers that have already been updated.

e.g.

```
Dictoinary<string,string> updatedSerialNumbers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (FillinEntity fin in fillin2) 
{
fin.ModifiedBy = loggedUser;
if (updatedSerialNumbers.Contains(fin.SerialNumber) == false)
{ 
  intResult = pBAL.UpdatetoShipped(fin);
  updatedSerialNumbers.Add(fin.SerialNumber,fin.SerialNumber);
}
```

Something like this should sort out your problem.